# Why does Angular read $scope more than needed?

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I noticed that Angular is less-than-conservative when it comes to reading $scope properties. When the app/controller first instantiate, each bound property defined in the model exposed via $scope is read twice. When any property changes, all the bound properties are read again.

Can someone explain why (or am I doing something incorrectly)?

Here's some code to illustrate.

I defined two properties on an object so that I could `console.log` anytime the property is read.

#### The obj Object

```
var obj = [];

Object.defineProperty(obj, "a", {
    get: function(){
        console.log("get obj.a: " + this.aVal);
        return this.aVal;
    },
    set: function(val){
        this.aVal = val;
        console.log("set obj.a = " + this.aVal);
    }
});

Object.defineProperty(obj, "b", {
    get: function(){
        console.log("get obj.b: " + this.bVal);
        return this.bVal;
    },
    set: function(val){
        this.bVal = val;
        console.log("set obj.b = " + this.bVal);
    }
});
```

#### The Angular App:

```
var app = angular.module("App", [])
.controller("TestCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.foo = obj;
});
```

#### and HTML:

```
<div ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="foo.a"></input>
        <input type="text" ng-model="foo.b"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### The result

The console log is as follows:

when first running the app both properties are called twice each:

```
get obj.a: undefined
get obj.b: undefined
get obj.a: undefined
get obj.b: undefined
```

when entering "x" for obj.a, both properties are read again

```
set obj.a = x
get obj.a: x
get obj.b: undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular handles two-way binding. The way it does it is through dirty checking. It checks any watched property at the top of the digest and then at the bottom of the digest (twice). It then compares the values to see if anything changed. This is the way it knows whether it needs to rebind the UI. Read [this article](http://hueypetersen.com/posts/2013/06/17/angular_is_slow) for reference.

The digest cycle runs anytime there is an `$apply` called on the scope.  Angular does this often (inside its own directives, e.g. `ng-click`).

Answer (score 0):

Try catch stack by firebug but it seem (as I know the angular) that it's from $watch implementation - it must firstly evaluate current hash of object to start "listen" to it's changes. So first reading of object is internal checking and second is for view. Not sure, but it have to read objects twice to implement $watch magic.