# Controller function called multiple times

Tags: angularjs

I was attempting to get AngularJs to apply an `active` class on a nav section depending upon the active route. My solution works fine but I noticed a curious behaviour -- more on that below. For now, here's how the active class is set in the HTML:

```
<ul class="menu" ng-controller="ControllerHeader">
  <li><a ng-class="{ active: isActive('/foo') }" href="#/foo">foo</a></li>
  <li><a ng-class="{ active: isActive('/bar') }" href="#/bar">bar</a></li>
  <li><a ng-class="{ active: isActive('/baz') }" href="#/baz">baz</a></li>
</ul>
```

`ControllerHeader` and `isActive` are defined as given:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [ ]);

app.controller( 'ControllerHeader', ['$scope', '$location',
  function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.isActive = function (location) {
      // multiple logging occurs: exactly 3*3 times
      console.log(location, $location.path());
      return location === $location.path();
    };
  }
] );
```

The issue I've noticed is that `isActive` above is called **3 * 3 times**!  Could someone please explain why?  How can I fix it that such that it is called **once** per item only?

Comment: It's called everytime a `$digest` cycle is triggered, which is a lot. Unless it's causing performance issues, don't worry about it.

Comment: does your route defines the controller as well? hows your route defined? are you using ui-router? or ng-route?

Comment: First question I had on Angular - a possible duplicate of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908130/why-does-angular-read-scope-more-than-needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Angular 1.3+, you can use the `::` operator to only evaluate the expression once:

```
<ul class="menu" ng-controller="ControllerHeader">
  <li><a ng-class="::{ active: isActive('/foo') }" href="#/foo">foo</a></li>
  <li><a ng-class="::{ active: isActive('/bar') }" href="#/bar">bar</a></li>
  <li><a ng-class="::{ active: isActive('/baz') }" href="#/baz">baz</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you are using an older version of Angular, you can use a third party library such as [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce)

As for why this is happening without binding once, indeed it is covered by many other questions. If you want the class to be dynamically set depending on angular context, Angular *need* to execute the function to check its value. That is called executing the watchers during a digest cycle, and this is done often.

Comment: it doesn't seems to work if binded on a function that return a random value. Is it correct? How can I achieve one time binding with a random function?

Comment: No, being random shouldn't matter, the first time the function return something that is not undefined should freeze the value (it doesn't make a difference for the browser if it's random or not). Feel free to create a question and present a reproducible code snippet if you need help

Answer (score 0):

All expression that you use in AngularJS get evaluated multiple times when a digest cycle runs. This is done for dirty checking which validates whether the current value of expression is different from the last value.

Comment: It *could* be evaluated multiple times on a digest. Typically, it's once. And this question has been asked in one flavor or another many times. Why not find a duplicate rather than provide yet-another-answer?